# nodeId to Element handle

Tags: puppeteer

Is there some elegant way how to get an element handle from `nodeId`? I get a list of all nodes (and nodeIds) by

```
const nodes = await page._client.send("DOM.querySelectorAll", {
  nodeId: doc.root.nodeId,
  selector: "*"
});
```

where `nodes.nodeIds` is a list of integers. And somehow I would like to run

```
const html = await page.$eval(nodeId, node => node.offsetParent === null);
```

To check if the element is visible. The problem is that `page.$eval` expects string (selector) as a first argument.

I could add a custom attribute through `DOM.setAttributeValue` and then query that through `page.$eval` but that seems hacky. So is there some more direct way how to go from `devtool-protocol` nodeIds to Puppeteer's `ElementHandle`?

Comment: Is it not an option to run `page.$$` instead of your first code snippet? You could then pass an element handles to `page.evaluate(.., handle)`.

Comment: There are some other things I am using `nodeIds` for, like `CSS.getMatchedStylesForNode` to get all styles (there is no alternative in Puppeteer for that). So I could do an extra `page.$$` call but would rather prefer to use `nodeIds` instead. Since Puppeteer is a wrapper around devtools-protocol, there should be a way how those two are directly linked, right?

Comment: Yes, this should be possible. There is a remoteObject attached to each element handle. Maybe you can get the nodeId from `elHandle._remoteObject.objectId` and then use `page.$$` and work with the element IDs instead? Can't say for sure if this would work, but maybe it helps you.

Comment: It seems that `objectId !== nodeId` so this API doesn't work https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/CSS#method-getComputedStyleForNode

Comment: Actually it's possible to use `DOM.requestNode` to convert objectId into nodeId (my answer is bellow). Thanks!

Comment: One may be able to convert a nodeId to an Elementhandle by getting the outerHTML of the node and trying to find the node by matching the outerHTML. using "DOM.getOuterHTML"

Answer (score 2):

So there is a way how to go from Puppeteer's `ElementHandle` to `nodeId`.

```
const element = page.$('a');
const node = await page._client.send("DOM.requestNode", {
  objectId: element._remoteObject.objectId
});
// <- { nodeId: 1 }
```

My original question asks for the other direction (nodeId -> ElementHandle) but I can work with this. It's also more practical to use Puppeteer by default whenever possible.

Comment: page._client is now a function  → page._client().send

Answer (score 0):

```js
const elementHandle = await page.$("a"))
const backaendNodeId = 10 // get from CDP
const newElementHandle = elementHandle.realm.adoptBackendNode(backaendNodeId)
```

---

Example:

```js
const elementToFindById = await page.$("input");
const exampleCDPInfo = await elementToFindById.remoteObject();

const {
  node: { backendNodeId },
} = await client.send("DOM.describeNode", {
  // uses nodeId,objectId, or backendNodeId to find node informaton
  objectId: exampleCDPInfo.objectId,
});
//need access to realm property to get access to adoptBackendNode function
const randomElement = await page.$("html");
const newHandle = await randomElement.realm.adoptBackendNode(backendNodeId);

//show you've found the element 
console.log(await newHandle.evaluate((e) => e.outerHTML))
```

---

There is a function in the internally used [realm](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/864ebc86c9e472c5c12bf498f37783804a43cae3/packages/puppeteer-core/src/bidi/ElementHandle.ts#L30C1-L32C4) property of an ElementHandle which has an [adoptBackendNode](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/packages/puppeteer-core/src/bidi/Sandbox.ts#L112) function that takes a backendnode and create an elementHandle

```js
  override async adoptBackendNode(
    backendNodeId?: number
  ): Promise<JSHandle<Node>> {
    const {object} = await this.environment.client.send('DOM.resolveNode', {
      backendNodeId: backendNodeId,
    });
    return new BidiElementHandle(this, {
      handle: object.objectId,
      type: 'node',
    });
  }
}
```